# Depth of BSTree node ( java )

Tags: java

I stuck in depth of BSTree node
does anyone have algorithm or code for finding the depth of BSTree node???
thanks

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear? Is the depth of the tree defined as the height of the tree?? is you BST an AVL (balanced tree)??

Comment: Also, is your BST data structure augmented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Psuedocode:

```
Function Depth
    If the right child isn't null, set left_depth to Depth(left_child), else set left_depth to 0.
    If the left child isn't null,set right_depth to Depth(right_child), else set right_depth to 0.
    return maximum(left_depth, right_depth) + 1;
```

See [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090428163320AArYVQr) posted code.